# Block SOAP request generated by Sudzc

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, soap, sudzc

I'm working on an application that uses [Sudzc](http://sudzc.com/) to interface with a SOAP web-service. The templates generated by the service works well, apart some modification `SoapRequest.h`, and some changes to the object serialization.
By default, the template offers the possibility to send the SOAP request using a method already created like this:

```
MyService* service = [MyService service];
[service login:self action:@selector(handleLogin:) user:@"user" password:@"pass"];
```

Once the request is finished, control is given to the handler with the value returned by the SOAP response like this:

```
- (void) handleLogin: (id) value{
  //cast value to your object
}
```

What I would like to know is if there is a possibility to block the request made, rather than by force to end the request.
For example, if the user makes a request from a `UINavigationController` who has `backButton` active (i know i could disable it until the request has been completed), but if the user returns to the previous controller, i would like to block the active request.

I hope it is clear(let me know if it is not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the method from your service actually returns a SoapRequest* object that you can use to manage the request, including canceling it.  For instance, you could do this...

```
MyService* service = [MyService service];
SoapRequest* request = [service login:self action:@selector(handleLogin:) user:@"user" password:@"pass"];
[request cancel];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 Perfect. Thanks for your rapid response Jason, and thanks for this great project.

Answer (score 0):

why not asking them on https://twitter.com/#!/sudzc ?

I don't know Sudzc, but I always create a Method `cancelConnection` in my services that can be called from dealloc in a UINavigationController. They have certainly done the same. Good luck